# How to set stdin_open = true and tty = true via terraform docker provider

Tags: docker, terraform

Is it any way to set stdin_open: true and tty: true, creating a container via terraform?

Currently I'm trying using the below provider via terraform 0.14:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/kreuzwerker/docker/latest

The current configuration is below:

```
resource "docker_container" "container" {
name    = var.container_name
  image   = var.image
  restart = var.restart
  networks_advanced {
    name = var.network_name
  }
  dynamic "volumes" {
    for_each = var.volumes
    iterator = index
    content {
          container_path  = index.value.container_path
          read_only = false
          host_path = index.value.host_path
    }
  }
  dynamic "ports" {
    for_each = var.ports
    iterator = index
    content {
          internal = index.value.internal
          external = index.value.external
          protocol = index.value.protocol
    }
  }
  capabilities {
    add = var.cap_add
    drop = var.cap_drop
  }
  env = var.environments
  dynamic "devices" {
    for_each = var.devices
    iterator = index
    content {
          host_path = index.value.host_path          
    }
  }
  command = var.command
  privileged = var.privileged
  attach = var.attach
}
```

and I'm try to replicate via terraform the container created via docker-compose

```
vpn:
      container_name: express-vpn
      image: polkaned/expressvpn
      environment:
        - ACTIVATION_CODE=${EXPRESSVPN_CODE}
      cap_add:
        - NET_ADMIN
      devices: 
        - /dev/net/tun
      stdin_open: true
      tty: true
      command: /bin/bash
      privileged: true
      restart: unless-stopped
      ports:
        -
```

Without the tty,stdin_open parameters, the container stop after creation

Comment: Could you update your question to include the configuration you've tried to run so far, and the output Terraform produced when you tried to run it? Your current question is broad and unlikely to get a good answer on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I think that you've opened [a GitHub issue in the Docker provider repository](https://github.com/kreuzwerker/terraform-provider-docker/issues/120) about this and it seems that one of the maintainers acknowledged it, so I think that suggests that what you're trying to do isn't possible with the current Docker provider release. I think you or someone else would need to contribute a change to the Docker provider to make those features available. 

Comment: @MartinAtkins, I found some time to contribute on the library and I did my pull request to include the extra properties. I'm able to compile the provider locally, so it's working with my local version and able to create and run my VPN container.

Answer (score 0):

Available from 2.11.0

[Ref] (https://github.com/kreuzwerker/terraform-provider-docker/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2110-january-22-2021)